# Mysql Select one row for each value of a colum

Tags: mysql, random

I have a table like this :

```
ID - CatID - Value
1      1      foo
2      2      bar
3      2      barbar
4      1      foobar
5      1      barfoo
6      2      foofoo
```

And what I need is to select randomly one row of each CatId (in this example it should 2 rows randomly). I tried with sub-query and Join on itself but I'm not sure it's as nice as it cool be... So if you have an idea on how to do it nicely it would be nice to help.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slow, but works:
select * from (select * from Tbl order by rand()) as t1 group by CatID

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you say ot's not very efficient, that's what I use right now.